# Inverse of a $4 \times 4$ matrix with variables

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I missed my class on the inverses of matrices. I'm catching up well, but there's a problem in the book that got me stumped.

It's a $4 \times 4$ matrix that is almost an identity matrix, but whose bottom row is $a,b,c,d$ instead of $0,0,0,1$.

$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
0 &1  &0  &0 \\ 
 0& 0 & 1 &0 \\ 
a &b  & c & d
\end{pmatrix}$$

Any pointers?

Comment: Your book should have (in its section on inverses) taking a matrix, augmenting it with the identity matrix, and then row reducing the left hand side to the identity matrix, leaving the inverse on the right hand side.  This method should work particularly quickly for your particular matrix.

Comment: My book has small appendix on inverses, it doesn't cover it very well. My teacher was teaching most of it in class, but I missed the last class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that one way to compute an inverse is by forming the augmented matrix

$$
(A \vert I)
$$
and then using Gaussian elimination to completely row-reduce $A$. The final result will be of the form
$$
(I \vert A^{-1}).
$$

So, in this case, you would write
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
a & b & c & d & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and the first step would be to add $-a \times$ (first row) to (last row), i.e.
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & b & c & d & -a & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

etc.

Comment: So would I continue along these lines and end up with:
1,0,0,0  1,0,0,-d      
0,1,0,0  0,1,-c,0      
0,0,1,0  0,-b,1,0     
0,0,0,1  -a,0,0,1

Well my I can't seem to format this. 
Would the top row on the inverse side look like 1,0,0,-d?

Comment: You will never have to modify the top row; once you have eliminated the $a$ $b$ and $c$ from the left side, the bottom row will look like $0,0,0,d,-a,-b,-c,1$. The last step is to divide by $d$, so you get $-a/d, -b/d, -c/d, 1/d$ as the bottom row on the inverse side.

Comment: and to format a matrix, you can use `\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i\end{bmatrix}` That gets typeset as $\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\ g & h & i\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 3):

The systematic way to compute an inverse to matrix $A$ is as follows.

1. Adjoin the identity to $A$, i.e. $[A|I]$, to form a matrix with $n$ rows and $2n$ columns.
2. Perform row reduction to turn $A$ into the identity.

3a. If you can't, i.e. there's a row of all zeroes, then $A$ is not invertible.

3b. If you can, the result will be $[I|B]$, for some matrix $B$.  This $B$ is the inverse of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Using [SymPy Live](http://live.sympy.org), we compute the RREF of the augmented matrix:

```
>>> a, b, c, d = symbols('a b c d')
>>> M = Matrix(([1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0],[0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0],[a,b,c,d,0,0,0,1]))
>>> M
[1  0  0  0  1  0  0  0]
[                      ]
[0  1  0  0  0  1  0  0]
[                      ]
[0  0  1  0  0  0  1  0]
[                      ]
[a  b  c  d  0  0  0  1]
>>> M.rref()
([1  0  0  0   1    0    0   0], [0, 1, 2, 3])
 [                            ]               
 [0  1  0  0   0    1    0   0]               
 [                            ]               
 [0  0  1  0   0    0    1   0]               
 [                            ]               
 [            -a   -b   -c   1]               
 [0  0  0  1  ---  ---  ---  -]               
 [             d    d    d   d]
```

Viewing the matrix as a **block matrix**

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
0 &1  &0  &0 \\ 
 0& 0 & 1 &0 \\
\hline 
a &b  & c & d
\end{array}\right] = 
\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
\mathrm I_3 & 0_3\\ 
\hline 
\mathrm r^T & d
\end{array}\right]$$

Assuming that $d \neq 0$,

$$\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
0 &1  &0  &0 \\ 
 0& 0 & 1 &0 \\
\hline 
a &b  & c & d
\end{array}\right]^{-1} = 
\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
\mathrm I_3 & 0_3\\ 
\hline 
\mathrm r^T & d
\end{array}\right]^{-1} =
\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
\mathrm I_3 & 0_3\\ 
\hline 
-d^{-1} \mathrm r^T & d^{-1}
\end{array}\right] =
\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
0 &1  &0  &0 \\ 
 0& 0 & 1 &0 \\
\hline 
-\frac ad & -\frac bd  & -\frac cd & \frac 1d
\end{array}\right]$$